# Showing that the Dirichlet problem on a bounded region has a solution iff an approximation condition for the boundary function holds

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, maximum-principle

Let $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb R^n, \Omega \neq \emptyset$ be open and bounded. For a continuous function $f: \partial \Omega \to \mathbb R$, we define the following function $\mathcal P[f](x): \overline \Omega \to \mathbb R$ via

$$\mathcal P[f](x) := \sup\{u(x) : u \in S_f\}$$

where $S_f$ is the set of "subfunctions" with respect to $f$ (i.e. the set of all continuous functions $u: \overline \Omega \to \mathbb R$ which are subharmonic on $\Omega$ and for which we have $u \mid_{\partial \Omega} \leq f$).

I now want to show: let $f: \partial \Omega \to \mathbb R$ be continuous. Then the Dirichlet problem

$$ \begin{cases} \Delta u = 0 & \text{on } \Omega \\ u \mid_{\partial \Omega} = f \end{cases} \tag{D}$$

has a solution on $\Omega$ if and only if $\mathcal P[-f] = - \mathcal P[f]$ on $\overline \Omega$.

For the direction "$\Leftarrow$", I'm given the hint I should first show that $P[f] \mid_{\partial \Omega} = f$.

I'm not really sure how to approach any of these directions. For the direction "$\Leftarrow$", I have a theorem which gives me that $\mathcal P[f](x)$ is harmonic, so I if I show that $P[f] \mid_{\partial \Omega} = f$ like mentioned in the hint, then it would immediately follow that $\mathcal P[f](x)$ solves the given Dirichlet problem. I don't really know though how I can derive $P[f] \mid_{\partial \Omega} = f$ from $\mathcal P[-f] = - \mathcal P[f]$.

Conversely, if I assume that $u$ is a solution of the given Dirichlet problem, I'd guess I'd also have to show that $\mathcal P[f](x) = u$, and then somehow derive $\mathcal P[-f] = - \mathcal P[f]$ by that? But I can't seem to work out the details for that direction either. I have standard tools like the maximum principle, Louisville's theorem for harmonic functions, etc. at my disposal, and I'd guess I'll need to use one of those at some point, but I'm not really sure how.

Comment: Hint 1) By definition of the function $P[f]$, you know that $P[f] \leq f$ on $\partial \Omega$. If you now use that $-P[f] = P[-f]$, you should be able to prove the direction $\Leftarrow$.

Comment: Hint 2) What uniqueness results do you know for the Dirichlet problem?

Comment: @Mike Thank you. For the direction $\Leftarrow$, I think I could deduce $\mathcal P[f] = f$ on $\partial \Omega$ now with the presumption $-P[f] = P[-f]$. That means that for $\Leftarrow$, I now have harmonicity on $Omega$ and equality to $f$ on the boundary of $\Omega$. However, I think was I still don't know (and would need for this direction) is that $P[f]$ is continuous (on all of $\overline \Omega$)?

Comment: @Mike Also, I'm unfortunately not sure if I know anything helpful here for the uniqueness of solutions for the Dirichlet problem... is there any result in particular that you are thinking of that could help here?

Comment: Ad2) Assume that $u$ is a solution to the Dirichlet problem. You would like to show that $P[f| = u$ in $\Omega$. One way of doing this is to show that $P[f]$ is also a solution to the Dirichlet problem and then use the uniqueness of the solution to the Dirichlet problem to deduce the claim. One additional tip: What problem does $P[-f]$ solve?